# clear() function and updateDisplay() function doesn't work when I click

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
```

JavaScript

```
class Calculator { 
constructor (previousOperandTextElement,currentOperandTextElement) 
{
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
}

updateDisplay()
{
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerHTML = this.currentOperand
    this.previousOperandTextElement.innerHTML = this.previousOperand
}
    clear() 
{
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerHTML = ''
    this.previousOperandTextElement.innerHTML = ''
    this.operation = undefined
}
```

}

```
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')


allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button =>
{
calculator.clear()
})
```

[I input 3 for previousElement and 4 for currentElement][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0xSp.png

[So now I tried to pressed the AC and the screen cleared][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlE39.png

[but when I tried to pressed a number again the number that I recently cleared just pop up and the number that I pressed concatenate to the currentElement][3][3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZgl6.png

```
allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button =>
{
calculator.clear()
})
```

So now I added the updateDisplay() to update the screen

```
allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button =>
{
calculator.clear()
calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

Nothing works, the clear function doesn't work

Comment: Can you please provide minimal example is SOSnippet?

Comment: @kidDeletes What means your comment? By the way, have you checked browsers console for errors? Have you already tried to add outputs to browsers console to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: how can i add pictures in this section?

Comment: In the comment section not possible.